# changeing pptp client default port

Tags: linux, pptp, pptp-client

I have a pptpd server running on debian. It does not use the default port of 1723 (for some reason), and some pptp client on ubuntu and suse linux. How can I connect to my pptp server?

Comment: down vote is helpful. please give me a comment.

Answer (score 0):

One choice is to modify/re-compile,
[change default PPTP TCP port](https://serverfault.com/questions/345674/change-default-pptp-tcp-port)

Another is to change the /etc/services file as indicated here,
http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/596670

As for the client side use mangling rules to get around the issue if there isn't an option (I don't use the software personally) or else modify/re-compile.

Comment: The question is about pptp client configuration. These links refer to pptp server configuration.

Comment: **As for the client side use mangling rules to get around the issue if there isn't an option (I don't use the software personally) or else modify/re-compile source code (if available).**

Comment: Thanx. I didn't saw that.